# Notifications don't open

Tags: release-hera, notifications

I'm on Eos 5.1.7 Hera, and when I click a notification in the list it doesn't open. It's the same problem with every app. I've noticed there's no matter openning it by clicking on the bubble when showing.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it is expected behavior:

> ..soon we will be able to support notifications with buttons so you
> can take action quickly without having to navigate away from the
> things you’re focused on.

From:  [Platform Changes in elementary OS 6](https://blog.elementary.io/platform-changes-in-elementary-os-6/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer